# Iterative Fibonacci number generator in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, fibonacci-sequence

I have very limited experience in Java and slightly more in C# (just doing Advent of Code problems last month), so I'm not familiar with how to write idiomatic Kotlin.

This class implements an infinite generator for the Fibonacci sequence.

```kotlin
import java.math.BigInteger

class FibonacciGenerator {
    private var fibs = arrayListOf<BigInteger>(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE)
    fun get(idx: Int): BigInteger {
        while (fibs.size <= idx) {
            val nextNum: BigInteger = fibs[fibs.size - 1] + fibs[fibs.size - 2]
            fibs.add(nextNum)
        }
        return fibs[idx]
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a test program that verifies at least part of the sequence is correct?  That's worth including in the review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few points:

- It is common practice to create mutable list without specifying implementation details using `mutableListOf`. Also I'd expect `LinkedList` to perform better than ArrayList, but that is very JVM-specific - there is no `linkedListOf`, but you can [create it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65818602/4070660) using Java API and use it. `ArrayList` would have to constantly reallocate more memory as the list grows bigger and you are not really using advantages of it (fast access), since you are always accessing only last 2 items in the array.
- Get method name is pretty generic. It doesn't say if you always cache it, calculate, etc. Not sure what would be better - maybe calculateUntil, with parameter `index` or generateUntil, since you are using `Generator` suffix.
- In some cases you don't need to specify type, it is already assumed from the code:

  ```
  arrayListOf(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE)
  ...
  val nextNum = fibs[fibs.size - 1] + fibs[fibs.size - 2]
  ```
- Use `.last()` method for accessing last element in the list. Consider creating extension function for accessing second last to improve readability and for consistency reasons (that may be an overkill :) ):

  ```
  return fibs.last()
  ```
- If using `last` is not appropriate, you can use `lastIndex` property rather than `fibs.size - 1`.
- I'd rename `fibs` to something more obvious like `calculatedList` (or generated.
- I assume you never wanna reassign `fibs`, in that case `var` is not necessary and you can use `val`.
- Think is is good idea to extract the functionality, that adds new item to the sequence into a separate method.

Overall, I imagine final code to something close to this (not sure about naming):

```
import java.math.BigInteger


fun <T> List<T>.secondLast(): T {
    if (size < 2)
        throw NoSuchElementException("List is not big enough to return second last")
    return this[lastIndex - 1]
}

class FibonacciGenerator {
    private val generatedList = mutableListOf(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE)
    private fun addAnotherItem() {
        generatedList.add(generatedList.last() + generatedList.secondLast())
    }

    fun generateUntilIndex(index: Int): BigInteger {
        while (generatedList.size <= index) {
            addAnotherItem()
        }
        return generatedList[index]
    }
}
```